# CSS Background image error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: css, path

This is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Trial </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="trial.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container1">
      <p>
        Hello
      </p>
    </div>
  
    <img src="D:\Trial Website\Grow Image.jpg" alt="image">
  </body>
</html>
```

Image file location seems to be working in HTML in image tag, but it is not working in css where I use the same file location.

This is my CSS code:

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

.container1 {
  background-image: url(D:\Trial Website\Grow Image.jpg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: just add this in css: `background: url("Grow Image.jpg")`;

Comment: Check the path, try replacing \ with /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put URL that is web accessible, not path.

So if your webroot is under `Trial Website`, then do

`<img src="/Grow Image.jpg" alt="image"/>`
`background: url("/Grow Image.jpg") ;`

Answer (score 0):

Place the resource path within quotes and the path should follow web standards, i.e, use forward slashes while defining a path. 
Change this:

```
background-image: url(D:\Trial Website\Grow Image.jpg);
```

To:

```
background-image: url("/Trial Website/Grow Image.jpg");
```

This shall fix the issue.